# Combine multiple columns within multiple rows based on value of a column up until change in value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Referring to the attached image with sample data, I would like to combine date, person, and note from multiple rows into 1 row with line breaks for each set of combined values. Each note takes up a row with Name and ID blank, so every row under the main row with values will need to be combined. See attached image for data, and desired output.

Sample Data:

```
+-------+--------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------+
| Name  |      ID      |       Date       | Person  |         Notes         |
+-------+--------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------+
| Danny | UID11224512  | 11/5/2019        | Joe     | <p>Note for Danny</p> |
|       |              | 11/5/2019        | John    | <p>Note 2</p>         |
| Joe   | UID11224956  | 11/5/2019 18:54  | Someone | <p>Note 1</p>         |
|       |              | 11/5/2019 18:54  | Someone | <p>Note 2</p>         |
| Jane  | UID11224959  | 11/5/2019 18:54  | Danny   | <p>Note 1 </p>        |
|       |              | 11/5/2019 17:33  | Shawn   | <p>Note 3</p>         |
|       |              | 11/6/2019 18:54  | Jane    | <p>Note 2</p>         |
| Tom   | UID115466652 |                  |         |                       |
| Eric  | UID168998955 |                  |         |                       |
| Paula | UID166559885 |                  |         |                       |
| Frank | UID112249569 | 11/5/2019 18:54  | Someone | <p>Note 1</p>         |
|       |              | 11/6/2019 18:54  | Someone | <p>Note 2</p>         |
|       |              | 11/7/2019 18:54  | Someone | <p>Note 3</p>         |
|       |              | 11/8/2019 18:54  | Someone | <p>Note 4</p>         |
|       |              | 11/9/2019 18:54  | Someone | <p>Note 5</p>         |
|       |              | 11/10/2019 18:54 | Someone | <p>Note 6</p>         |
| Paul  | UID1665588   |                  |         |                       |
+-------+--------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+-------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| Name  |      ID      |               Notes               |
+-------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| Danny | UID11224512  | "11/5/2019 (Joe) - Note for Danny |
|       |              | 11/5/2019 (John) - Note 2"        |
| Joe   | UID11224956  | "11/5/2019 (Someone) - Note 1     |
|       |              | 11/5/2019 (Someone) - Note 2"     |
| Jane  | UID11224959  | "11/5/2019 (Danny) - Note 1       |
|       |              | 11/5/2019 (Shawn) - Note 2        |
|       |              | 11/5/2019 (Jane) - Note 3"        |
| Tom   | UID115466652 |                                   |
| Eric  | UID168998955 |                                   |
| Paula | UID166559885 |                                   |
| Frank | UID112249569 | "11/5/2019 (Someone) - Note 1     |
|       |              | 11/6/2019 (Someone) - Note 2      |
|       |              | 11/7/2019 (Someone) - Note 3      |
|       |              | 11/8/2019 (Someone) - Note 4      |
|       |              | 11/9/2019 (Someone) - Note 5      |
|       |              | 11/10/2019 (Someone) - Note 6"    |
| Paul  | UID1665588   |                                   |
+-------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------------------------+
```

Sample Data:
[image: Sample Data]

Wanted Output:
[image: Wanted Output]

Comment: Consider making it easy for those who want to help, by posting your sample data as text. I don't have an easy way of pasting a screenshot into Excel.  Do you?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sorry about that. Didn't realize that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

- Select some cell in your data table

  - `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
  - In the Power Query UI: `Home => Advanced Editor`
  - Make note of the Table name in line 2
  - Paste the MCode below into the window
  - Change the table name in Line 2 to your Actual table name
  - Read the code, comments and examine the `Applied Steps` window to understand what is going on.

**Brief Algorithm**

- `Fill down` the blanks for the Name and ID columns
- `Group` by the Name and ID columns
- Extract the **First** date, person and note as you show into separate columns
- Combine all the Dates/Persons/Notes (separated by linefeeds) for the last column

**M Code**

*In the code below, be sure to change the Table name in Line2 to your actual table name*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"ID", type text}, {"Date", type datetime}, {"Person", type text}, {"Notes", type text}}),
    
//Fill down to fill in the blanks for Name and ID columns
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type",{"Name", "ID"}),

//Group on Name and ID -- should be the same so this is a double check.
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Name", "ID"}, {

//For each Name/ID
    //Extract first Date as a date string if it has no time component, otherwise leave it as a datetime 
        {"Date", each if DateTime.Time([Date]{0}) = #time(0,0,0)
                            then DateTime.ToText([Date]{0},"MM/dd/yy")
                            else [Date]{0}},
    //Extract first Person
        {"Person", each [Person]{0}},

    //extract first Note
        {"Notes.1", each [Notes]{0}},

    //Extract and combine, for each note, the Date, person, and note
    //  Then split the combination for each entry by linefeed.
        {"Notes.2", (t)=> Text.Combine(
                            List.Generate(() => [Count=1, 
                            dt =DateTime.ToText(t[Date]{0},"MM/dd/yyyy") & " (" & 
                                t[Person]{0} & 
                                ") - " & t[Notes]{0}],
                         each [Count] <= Table.RowCount(t), 
                         each [Count = [Count] + 1, dt = DateTime.ToText(t[Date]{[Count]},"MM/dd/yyyy") & 
                                    " (" & t[Person]{[Count]} & 
                                    ") - " & t[Notes]{[Count]}],
                         each [dt]),"#(lf)")
                    }
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

In Excel, you will need to format the `Notes.2` column to `Wrap Text` and the `Date` column to `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm`  (*In the date column, the dates without times get returned as Text strings, so won't have the same format -- again as you show in your question*)

Comment: You're awesome. One question. Noticed that on some of the notes, they are wrapped in <p>. How can I remove those? 

EDIT: For below question, I just deleted the extract sections and it seems to work. 

Also, how can I delete the original Date, person, and note column and just keep the final combined notes.2 column? Thank you so much.

Comment: @enyceexdanny I was going by the screenshot of your results.  If you don't want those particular columns, the "cleanest" way to get rid of them is to delete the lines of code where they are being generated in the `Table.Group` function.  And change `Notes.2` to just `Notes` on the remaining line of code in that function.

Comment: @enyceexdanny For the `<p>` and `</p>`, PQ has a replace Values option from the UI which you can use.

Comment: Thank you. You're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set "Wrap Text" from the Home ribbon for the whole comments column. Use this formula to combine text values with line breaks:

```
="comment1" & CHAR(10) & "Comment2"
```

If you are combining two separate tables, its may be worth investigating Power Query in Excel.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that wasn't my question. Would appreciate if you can see the sample data and the desired output. It's a bit more complex than that. Thank you